# Enable Memcached in EE 2.9.2: problems

Tags: ee2, config, cache, caching

I am trying to get Memcached working on my EE (2.9.2) website. I have `memcached` installed correctly (both Memcache and the PHP extension) and running as a daemon:

```
% ps -ef|grep memcache
user   pid   1  0  16:45 ?   00:00:00 memcached -d -p 11211 -u memcached -m 64 -c 1024 -P /path/to/memcached.pid
```

I have added the following code to my `config.php` file as per the [docs](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/general/system_configuration_overrides.html#memcached):

```
$config['memcached'] = array(
    array(
        'host' => 'XX.XXX.XX.XXX',
        'port' => 11211,
        'weight' => 2,
    ),
);
```

However, when I try to select `Memcached` from the drop-down list of options under *CP Home > Administration > General Configuration* I see the following (in red):

```
Cannot connect to Memcached, using File driver instead
```

I cannot understand why this is happening and EE's logging of the problem is 100% non-existent (there is nothing in the Apache error log, EE Control Panel log). Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same issue, worked with EE 2.8 but 2.9 and 2.9.2 giving me the same message you get. CE-Cache just works with Memcached and redis, so it seems to be EE that has some problems....

Comment: Since it seems like others are having this problem. It might be a good idea to submit a bug report to EllisLab.

Comment: I don't pay for EllisLab support. To submit a bug report costs (at a minimum, as of writing) $49 per month, which IMHO is daylight robbery. I will just buy CE-Cache, which sounds like it works as advertized, unlike EE 2.9.*

Comment: It does not cost money to submit bug reports.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for the trouble. This is an issue in EE 2.9 and will be fixed in the next release. For now, you can get around it by specifying the cache driver in your config.php:

```
$config['cache_driver'] = 'memcached';
```